# How do I call New-Object for a constructor which takes a single array parameter?

Tags: arrays, powershell, parameters, constructor

In PowerShell, I want to use `New-Object` to call a single-argument .Net constructor `new X509Certificate2(byte[] byteArray)`. The problem is when I do this with a byte array from powershell, I get

> New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "X509Certificate2" and the argument count: "516".

Answer (score 82, accepted):

This approach to using `new-object` should work:

```
$cert = new-object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate `
      -ArgumentList @(,$bytes)
```

The trick is that PowerShell is expecting an array of constructor arguments.  When there is only one argument and it is an array, it can confuse PowerShell's overload resolution algorithm.  The code above helps it out by putting the byte array in an array with just that one element.

**Update:** in PowerShell >= v5 you can call the constructor directly like so:

```
$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate]::new($bytes)
```

Comment: Two quibbles (and that's all they are): `(, $bytes)` is sufficient to construct the array; while `@(...)` ultimately works the same, it is not necessary and less efficient, because it constructs _another_ array (though in practice that will hardly matter).
It is not the the constructor-overload resolution that's the problem, but PowerShell's standard _parameter binding_: `-ArgumentList` is `[object[]]`-typed, so if you pass a single argument that is an array (or similar), that array's elements become _individual_ arguments to pass to the constructor; the extra array wrapper avoids that.

Comment: Neither of these constructs is working for me on PS version 5.0 on a Win7 client.
The first (w or w/o @) throws `Exception calling ".ctor" with 1 argument(s): "Cannot find the requested object." `    As if it's still trying to open a file name.
The second throws: `Cannot find type[[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate]::new] verify that an assembly containing this type is loaded.`

Comment: Okay, i figured it out.   The cert data was corrupted...evidently those are the errors you get.  Once I fixed that problem the form without the @ worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

Surprisingly to me, I tried this and it seems it works:

```
[byte[]] $certPublicBytes = something
$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate] $certPublicBytes
return $cert
```

I don't yet know by what magic it works, so your explanatory comments are appreciated. :)

(Note: I since found that using square-brackets-type-name as I did above, can also lead to other errors, such as 'Cannot convert value "System.Byte[]" to type "System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate". Error:
"Cannot find the requested object.' The explicit New-Object approach recommended by Keith seems better!)

Comment: By strongly-typing the array as [byte[]] instead of untyped (which is actually [object[]]) you are removing all ambiguity when selecting the correct constructor. PowerShell will look for a constructor when performing a cast if there is no implicit or explicit cast available.

Comment: Same, explicitly adding types does nothing. Checking the expression containing the bytes, it already has type byte[], and not object[]. Using Keith Hills suggestion works fine.